# ¿que debo tener en cuenta para no tener problemas a la hora de volver a generar mis aplicaciones en modo release para la tienda después de formatear?

Tags: android

Buen día, me gustaría pedirles un consejo :
Hace más de dos años que no le hago mantenimiento a mi pc y me gustaría formatearlo para limpiarlo, ¿que debo tener en cuenta para no tener problemas a la hora de volver a generar mis aplicaciones en modo release para la tienda después de formatear?, ¿solo es cuestión de guardar los. Jks?

Comment: Yo hace poco formateé mi pc y efectivamente sólo guardé el archivo `.jks` que usaba para generar la apk y no he tenido problemas en subirla al store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente solo hay que guardar las llaves (.jks) solo hay que crear algunas copias de seguridad y asegurarse de guardar la contraseña de la llave y del alias